# JS: Object.defineProperty() and Proxy

Tags: javascript, object, properties

What's the difference between [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)?
On my view they do really the same in essence being useful only for implementation of reactivity, validation and defaults.

So it just looks like `defineProperty` gives only a subset of features available with Proxy.
`defineProperty` changes original object when Proxy preserves the origin untouched. Proxy allows to set all at once and even in advance (like interception of member which is till not created). Proxy handles also function calls and has enough power to override constructor and delete operator.

If it's right, maybe we do not need `defineProperty` anymore.

Comment: So, what if we do need to mutate the original object?

Comment: @SebastianSimon hm, it looks like the reason. I can find only weak argument: a mutation (state change) is a bad practice (as ancient technique)

Comment: Also getters/setters for a few predetermined properties are much more efficient than a proxy. And they do allow individual definition, whereas a proxy handler *must* handle *all* properties.

Comment: I like the question. I had a similar one. Realized I hadn't fully understood the usefulness of defineProperty.